# Why doesn't this drop-down list do what it should?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a drop down list in asp.net using nested for loops in a view, as well as variables I've
passed from a controller. The value that is displayed to the user is supposed to be the name of a stop, and the value is an id of that stop. Both the names and the stop ids are in lists I've passed from the controller to the view. But, when the drop down list is displayed, the first stop name is repeated for the entire list. I know that the right stop id is being selected, but the name is repeating. Here is my code:

```
 <select id="stop" onchange="sendInfo();">

@foreach(var blah in ViewBag.foobar)
{
  foreach (var foo in ViewBag.stops)
    { 
      <option value="@foo">@blah</option>
    }
}
 </select>
```

foo is the stop id that is correctly used, but blah is the name of the stop name, which is repeated. I feel like I'm so close but not quite there. I hope this was clear enough, it is  confusing to explain.

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what it's supposed to.  What do you want to change?

Comment: blah keeps repeating itself-it keeps repeating the first element in the blah list in ViewBag.foobar. <option value="@foo"> is correct and iterates through each value in teh foo list, but @blah just doesn't iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive I understand what you're saying, but if there's a 1:1 relationship between stops and IDs, why don't you make a class containing both, like

```
public class Stop
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and pass in a list of those and do a single loop:

```
@{
    var stops = (IEnumerable<Stop>)ViewBag.Stops;
}

<select>
    foreach (var stop in stops)
    {
        <option value="@stop.Id">@stop.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally got this working based on your idea for using an array of classes. It also helped to simplify my code, and spurred me to use better names.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
        @{
            if(ViewBag.foo != null && ViewBag.blah != null && ViewBag.foo.Count == ViewBag.blah.Count)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.foo.Count; i++ )
                {
                    <option value="@ViewBag.foo[i]">@ViewBag.blah[i]</option>
                }
            }
        }
```

Also, a few tips:

1. Using two lists for related data is not appropriate. Why don't you have a single property, like a `Dictionary<string, string>`?
2. `foo` and `blah` are not their real name, right?
3. Avoid using `ViewBag` for functional-related data (like creating controls, as you are doing). For this situation, creating a specialized **view model** is preferred

Comment: Pretty sure should be Count, Length is for strings but foo will be a List or similar. I agree. Looks like the original code is picking a stop name and then outputting all stop numbers along side that, or vis versa. The indexes should be paired instead. Ideally I'd make a class/struct that contained the string and number representation so you don't end up with some weirdness of sort ordering not being the same, or something getting added to one list before another etc.

Comment: @Mike I agree that it could be much better designed. However, I usually don't give answers like "you should change your code", I prefer to focus on the problem described.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I got "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" for the line that has for(...) in it.

Comment: @Amanda_Panda did you change the `Length` to something else? What is `foo`, a `List<something>`?

Comment: @AndreCalil yeah, foo and blah are both lists, and both have rather horrible names admittedly

Comment: @Amanda_Panda So change `ViewBag.foo.Length` to `ViewBag.foo.Count`

Comment: I changed it to count, and still got "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" for the for loop